# Trying to run npm start command in the docker file in the background

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker.

I am trying to have a docker file built on ubuntu with apache2, .net core, node js.
I am trying to run the sample nodejs app in the file.
But every time the "npm run" command comes while building, it goes to creating the development server and doesn't go to the next step.

Is there a way I can run that in the background or come out of it like (ctl+c) we do on the terminal?

Here is the docker file:

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN echo "welcome to yellow pages"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN apt-get install -y apache2

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
RUN mkdir -p ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
RUN touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/yellowpages.conf
RUN echo '<VirtualHost *:80> \n\
    ServerName myserver.mydomain.com \n\
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost \n\
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html \n\
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log \n\
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined \n\
    </VirtualHost> \n'\
>> /etc/apache2/sites-available/yellowpages.conf

RUN cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/yellowpages.conf
RUN echo 'ServerName myserver.mydomain.com' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN a2ensite yellowpages.conf
RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN echo 'Hello, docker' > /var/www/index.html


# installing nodejs12 on to the container 
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN sudo sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# installing .net core 3.1 on to the container
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1
RUN dotnet --list-sdks
RUN dotnet --list-runtimes

#Running a demo node app

RUN npx create-react-app my-app

# COPY /my-app/package*.json ./
# RUN npm start

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]  
RUN cd my-app && nohup npm start
EXPOSE 80 
EXPOSE 3000
```

This is the output I get where I am stuck

[image: output]

Because of this Docker image is not being created as it is stuck in this step.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You should almost always run the three separate processes in three separate containers.    You cannot start background processes in a Dockerfile (everything is stopped at the end of each `RUN` command) and it will be much easier to manage and update the individual components if they're not combined into a single entity.

Comment: @DavidMaze you're suggesting that I should have 3 different files and 3 different containers to accommodate apache, .net, and node?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Docker Compose is a straightforward orchestration tool that can simplify setting this up.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to run a supervisor program like supervisord as the docker's entrypoint so that when it starts, Apache and NPM can start together.

Try https://riptutorial.com/docker/example/14132/dockerfile-plus-supervisord-conf as a starting point.

A light-weight alternative is to have a shell-scrpt as your starting point in which you run apache and Node process as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run npm in the background
npm start & 

# run apache in the foreground
/usr/sbin/apache2
```

**DockerFile**

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["/mystart_script.sh"]
...
```